# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function quote_smart(), 1 passed

Tags: php

I have a page to add tasks into my task management system. But I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function quote_smart(), 1 passed

How can I fix this problem? This is my code:

```
if ($exist){
    $msg = 'Task name already exist!';
}
else{
    //unwanted HTML (scripting attacks)
    $name1 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','taskmanager');
    $taskname = htmlspecialchars($taskname);

    //function
    $taskname = quote_smart($taskname);

    $name1 = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','taskmanager');
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO task_list (`taskname`, `ds`) VALUES ($taskname, '$des')";
    $result = mysqli_query($name1,$SQL);
    if($result){
        $msg = 'Task succesfully added.';
        $SQL = "CREATE TABLE $tsk (username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, accepted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)";
        mysqli_query($name1,$SQL);
    }
    else{
        $msg = "Error adding task";
    }
}
```

Comment: Such problems are solved by *understanding* the error. Here it tells you need to pass more arguments to the function than you've already given. In this case, you open the documentation for that func and read what arguments to pass.

Comment: Thank you it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

quote_smart takes two arguments quote_smart($var, $connection);

In your case you need:

```
$taskname = quote_smart($taskname, $name1);
```

You can see the examples here: https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/quote_smart/php-quote_smart-function-examples.html